# Optimize Join, Sum, Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a Tinder clone for a study project and I'm trying to do something very simple conceptually but it appears that my request is really too heavy.

#### Data Structure

I've created [this simple fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aff266/2) to visualize the database structure.
I've tried to put indexes on `user.id` `user.gender * user.orientation` `match.user1` `match.user2` `match.createdAt` with no luck.

#### Expected result

I want to find the people who have the less number of matches depending on gender, orientation, lastLogin and calendar date.
Users musn't be part of more than 4 matches during 24h so I look for users with <= 3 matches during the last 24h.

*Values in the following are hard coded for easy editing of the request and because I didn't took time to do this part for now.*

A match is composed of 2 users (user1 and user2).
The limit of 4 matches on the same day is a sum of when they appear as user1 and user2.

```
SELECT total_sum, userId
      FROM (
        SELECT u.id as userId, u.orientation as userOrientation, u.gender as userGender, m1.sum1, m2.sum2, (m1.sum1 + m2.sum2) AS total_sum
        FROM user u
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT user1, COUNT(user1) as sum1 
          FROM `match` 
          WHERE createdAt > DATE('2017-12-11 00:00:00') 
          GROUP BY user1
        ) m1
        ON m1.user1 = u.id
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT user2, COUNT(user1) as sum2 
          FROM `match` 
          WHERE createdAt > DATE('2017-12-11 00:00:00') 
          GROUP BY user2
        ) m2
        ON m2.user2 = u.id
        WHERE u.gender IN ('female')
        AND u.orientation IN ('hetero', 'bi')
        AND u.lastLogin > 1512873464582
      ) as total
      WHERE total_sum < 4
      ORDER BY total_sum ASC
      LIMIT 8
```

#### The issue

With tiny tables, request takes few ms but with medium tables (50k users, 200k matches), request takes ages (170s).

#### Optimizing

According to **@Thorsten Kettner** response, this is the [explain plan](https://pastebin.com/tCDqrb84) of his request when I run it into my test db after setting the indexes he advised:

#### Solution

I've ended up doing something easier.
First I flatened my match table by removing `user2` column. It double the size because now 1 match become 2 rows but allow me to do something very simpler and very efficient with proper indexes.
The first query is to manage users with no matches and the second one to handle user with matches. I don't have anymore the matchesLimit into the query as it add extra work for mysql and I just need to check the first result to see if matchNumber is <= 3.

```
(SELECT u.id, mc.id as nb_match, u.gender, u.orientation
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN match_composition mc 
ON (mc.matchedUser = u.id AND mc.createdAt > DATE('2017-12-11 00:00:00'))
WHERE u.lastLogin > 1512931740721 
AND u.orientation IN ('bi', 'hetero')
AND u.gender IN ('female')
AND mc.id IS NULL
ORDER BY u.lastLogin DESC)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT u.id, count(mc.id) as nb_match, u.gender, u.orientation
FROM match_composition mc
JOIN user u 
ON u.id = matchedUser
WHERE mc.createdAt > DATE('2017-12-11 00:00:00')
AND u.lastLogin > 1512931740721
AND u.orientation IN ('bi', 'hetero')
AND u.gender IN ('female')
GROUP BY matchedUser
ORDER BY nb_match ASC
LIMIT 8)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please provide your table details and explain more about the matching algorithm

Comment: indexing is vital when optimizing, so the DDL of the tables and an explain plan would help

Comment: "musn't have been matched more than 4 times" implies `<=4`.

Comment: @MHRasel I don't see what I could add. You have the description of what the matching algorythm must do and the columns you can use to do that. There is no hiden keys. Tell me what you don't understand and I will try to explain it better.

Comment: You need to look into indexing, particular on columns that are frequently included in `where` clauses. Also, in addition to what _philipxy_ said about `<` vs `<=`, what if someone's account happened to be created **on** midnight? You seem to be lax with comparison operators. You need `>=` midnight if you mean 'on or after this day'.

Comment: I guess you mean you are selecting people because you want to match them up not more than 4 times so you want the query to return people matched fewer than 4 times. Your post did not say that, as I quoted. You have edited to try to clarify but insufficiently because if you read your post you will see that your edit contradicts what I quoted & is still there, namely "I want to find the less matched people [...] They [...] mustn't have been matched more than 4 times." You need to change that to more than 3, and then your other edit is redundant. PS **[mcve]** including DDL & `explain` please.

Comment: @philipxy Totally clear and right. I meant, by the end of the day, they musn't have been matched more than 4 times but this information isn't relevant for the request.

Comment: @underscore_d You are right concerning dates. This exemple is not fully functionnal as hh:mm:ss is missing. It will be parametrized to be a date exactly 24h ago. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my question after commenting. I will see what I can do for the "matched" part

Comment: Hi. Comments are not for clarifications, please edit your question. Also "matched" as just used in your comment is itself confusing/misleading because you mean "matched" in the application domain--which you use but never explain--but in the context of the query it seems to mean "matched' in the sense of matching the where condition. Use enough words to be clear. Also please don't edit by appending more stuff, that doesn't make previous unclear stuff clear, just make the best up-to-date post you can. PS **MCVE** **DDL** **`explain`**

Comment: @philipxy I've done the requested changes, hope it's good now :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user can be matched as user1 or user2. We can use `UNION ALL` to get one record per user:

```
select user1 as userid from match union all select user2 as userid from match;
```

The complete query:

```
select
  u.id as userid,
  coalesce(um.total, 0) as total
from user u
left join
(
  select userid, count(*) as total
  from 
  (
    select user1 as userid from match where createdat > date '2017-12-11'
    union all 
    select user2 as userid from match where createdat > date '2017-12-11'
  ) m
  group by userid
) um on um.userid = u.id
where u.gender IN ('female')
  and u.orientation in ('hetero', 'bi')
  and u.lastlogin > 1512873464582
  and coalesce(um.total, 0) < 4
order by coalesce(um.total, 0);
```

You would have the following indexes for this:

```
create index idx_m1 on match (createdat, user1);
create index idx_m2 on match (createdat, user2);
create index idx_u on user (lastlogin, gender, orientation, id);
```

Comment: This is seriously working better than everything. But I'm still around 25s which is an enormous time to wait for an HTTP request. I wouldn't have expected this to be so hard... Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. So it's time to use `explain plan` and see what makes the query slow I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I've edited my question with explain plan in the **Optimization** section

Answer (score 2):

I guess you were right about your SQL skills. This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT u.id as userId, 
       u.orientation as userOrientation, 
       u.gender as userGender, 
       count(m.user1) total_sum
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN `match` m on (u.id in (m.user1, m.user2) 
                        and m.createdAt > DATE('2017-12-11 00:00:00'))
WHERE u.gender IN ('female')
  AND u.orientation IN ('hetero', 'bi')
  AND u.lastLogin > 1512873464582
having count(m.user1) <=4
ORDER BY total_sum ASC
LIMIT 8;
```

Edit: Covered also cases with no matches

Try to play around with indexing **match** table columns **user1, user1** and also with **User** table columns(or column combinations) you use in filters (gender for example), see what brings better performance.

Comment: Thanks Edgar but your request is even longer than mine ! (395s).
I've created an index on:  
user.id, match.user1, match.user2, user.gender * user.orientation but this is still super slow

Comment: @philipxy: What makes you say so? You do need an outer join in order to get the users that have no match record yet.

Answer (score 0):

From what you provide, I would create indexes on:
- match.user1
- match.user2
- match.createdAt
- user.id (unique, and probably a PK)
- user.lastLogin

I would also try to replace COUNT(user1) by COUNT(*), but it won't probably have a big impact.

Indexes on *user.gender* and *user.orientation* are probably useless: the efficiency of an index is somehow proportional to the variance of its underlying values. Therefore an index on a field with 2-3 distinct values is more costly than useful.

As for the DLL, try the following. I tried to force the filtering on `user` to be done BEFORE the joins with `match`, in case the query optimizer does not work properly (I have little experience with non MS databases)

```
SELECT total_sum, userId
FROM (SELECT u.id as userId, u.orientation as userOrientation, u.gender as userGender, m1.sum1, m2.sum2, (m1.sum1 + m2.sum2) AS total_sum
      FROM (SELECT * FROM user 
            WHERE gender = 'female'
            AND orientation IN ('hetero', 'bi')
            AND lastLogin > 1512873464582
            ) u
      INNER JOIN (SELECT user1, COUNT(*) as sum1 
                  FROM `match` 
                  WHERE createdAt > DATE('2017-12-11 00:00:00') 
                  GROUP BY user1
                  ) m1 ON m1.user1 = u.id
      INNER JOIN (SELECT user2, COUNT(*) as sum2 
                  FROM `match` 
                  WHERE createdAt > DATE('2017-12-11 00:00:00') 
                  GROUP BY user2
                  ) m2 ON m2.user2 = u.id
      ) as total
WHERE total_sum < 4
ORDER BY total_sum ASC
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Typically I have 2 genders and 3 orientations. Thanks for your answer.
I tried indexes as you advised but with no impact. I'm propably doing something wrong. I'm working on DDL now.